# height map related issue

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, perlin-noise

I am trying to make a program in Java that uses Perlin noise to make a black and white height map. I tried using the code from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160529013225/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) to implement the noise. I used the code below to try to make the noise make a height map but what I get is something like [this](http://www.filterforge.com/images/version3/script-api/z-animated-perlin.jpg) instead of getting a height map.

```
BufferedImage img;
img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );

int[] pixel = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

for(int i = 0; i < (WIDTH*HEIGHT); i++)
{
    pixel[i] = (int) perlin.PerlinNoise(i, i);   
}
```

Comment: Why do you use an RGB image if you only want grayscale (= *hight-map*)?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to draw onto the image if it was TYPE_BYTE_GRAY  or TYPE_USHORT_GRAY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` as follows: Create you noise-array of type `int[]` where the numbers in the array should be between [0,255]. Let's assume this pixel array is called `pixelData`, then the following should work

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 
                                     BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
img.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, pixelData);

File output = new File("image.jpg");
try {
  ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", output);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to have a complete example, then please look at the following question: [Issue with Perlin Noise in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19184419/1078614)

Comment: Is the permutation[] just random value's for each point you made up for the noise or do they have to be those values?

Comment: You mean in the linked *Issue with Perlin Noise in Java* post? This is not my code! It is a reference implementation by Perlin and honestly, I don't know the answer. You have to read the publication.